# How to add `overflow` to SelectableText in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, jquery-ui-selectable

There is `SelectableText` widget that allows you to make text selectable. But it misses the `overflow` parameter, which is required...

Is there any workaround, which can make it work? Or a similar solution?
Thanks!

Comment: I think that all text should be shown to select text.

Comment: If you use 'maxLines' parameter, you can limit vertical spread.

Comment: @kuku not exactly. it will limit the number of lines, but they will become scrollable, which is terrible...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just experienced this.
The problem is `overflow` hasn't been made the top level parameter in case of `SelectableText` as with `Text` in Flutter which suggests that it must be there, just not as the top level parameter which is true as it is in `TextStyle`.

Hence, to use `overflow` in `SelectableText`, change

```
SelectableText(
  text,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
)
```

to

```
SelectableText(
  text,
  style: TextStyle(
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, remember that when you want the space to expand, you can also use *Expanded* or *Flexible*.
Hope it helps.

```
Row(children: [
                  Text('Código de inscrição: '),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SelectableText(club.SignUpCode),
                  )
                ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case above solutions didn't work.
I found another solution using `ListTile`:

```
ListTile(
    title: SelectableText(
           text,
           toolbarOptions: const ToolbarOptions(
                  copy: true,
                  selectAll: true,
                  cut: true,
           ),
    ),
)
```

and it worked as `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` for me

Answer (score -1):

If the TextOverflow.clip effect is enough for you this did the trick for me:

```js
SelectableText("My text"
              maxLines: 1,
              scrollPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics())
```